# Is that correct? James Wilson's Sentence in House MD TV Sereies

Tags: word-order, negation

I am asking about the sentence this guy (James Wilson, House's best friend) says at 7:00 in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvDWtMVPyf8) video.
The transcription is:

> Okay, maybe. But he's our friend and this is his one chance to not be miserable.

I am curious about the ''one chance''. Does one chance work as only chance? Or should I wrote *his one-chance*?

Still, the biggest question is about the **to not be**. As far as I know, it is *not to*. For instance, tend not to, try not to, etc. or also in reported speech: they told us not to.
Is it wrong what he says then, or is this situation different from the ones I have cited?

PS: The video corresponds to Chapter 16, Season 5, *The Softer Side*, as you can see in its description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean "he's our friend", not "his our friend".

*His one chance* does indeed mean *his only chance*.

Both *not to be* and *to not be* are possible there. But *a choice not to be miserable* is a bit vague: we know what the choice is not, but what is it?  *A choice to not be miserable* is much stronger, even if in the end they mean the same thing.

Comment: There used to be a prejudice against so-called [split infinitives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive) - a rule that was made up by grammarians in the 19th century - so you may well have been taught only the _not to be_ form. But most grammarians and style-guides now accept them, though they oft6en advise against them except rfor a particular effect, as here.